# Generating Dynamic Forms

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a Web Page that contains 1 to many tabs.  Each tab has a dynamically created Form.  So if there are 4 tabs, I generate 4 forms dynamically in my controller in a foreach loop where I pass the $Id like so:

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
        $html .= $this->createHtml($id);
    }
```

To the following function

```
    private function createHtml($Id)
{
    $html .= '<div id="product_'.$Id.'">';
    $html .= '  <form id="form_'.$Id.'" name="form_'.$Id.'" class="formatted" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                    <fieldset class="border">
                        {{ form_row(product_form_'.$Id.'.product, {
                            \'note\' : \'Enter Something\'
                        })  }}
                    </fieldset>
                </form>';
    $html .= '  <br/>';
    $html .= '
                <div>
                    Some text
                </div>';
    $html .= '</div>';

   return $html;
}
```

So that function is called 4 times and keeps adding to $html.

I then pass `$html` and the 4 `product_form->createView()` to the twig and output the html like so:

```
{{html | raw}}
```

All the html div and form tags are rendered correctly but instead of rendering an input field for product, this gets displayed:

```
{{ form_row(product_form_'.$Id.'.product, { \'note\' : \'Enter Something\' }) }}
```

You see?  It doesn't recognize that as a symfony input field to render.  It thinks it's regular text.

I thought the | raw might have something to do with it so I adjusted my code to display `{{form_row... }}` without the | raw but that had no affect.

Comment: The `raw` method will not magically parse twig methods. Why don't you make use of a normal Twig template instead of the createHtml method you created now?

Comment: Twig, you're doing it wrong. The whole point of using a template system is to never, ever again have to use methods like "createHtml" and write things like <code>html .= "..."</code>.

Comment: The OP wrote a new question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642562/form-widget-with-dynamic-form-name